# Как сделать бэкап из cPanel с сохранением русских имен файлов?

Tags: хостинг

Я так полагаю, повсеместно существует проблема о невозможности создания бэкапов с сохранением русских букв. Как еще можно делать бэкап или как лучше залечить `cPanel`, чтобы русские имена файлов сохранялись нормально?

Comment: Не знаю таких проблем, и нафига создавать файлы русскими буквами.

Comment: сума сошли чтоли ? Русский язык - сила !

Comment: через FileZilla выкачать)))

Comment: Русский язык на Unix хосте - ***дебилизм***, прошу меня простить, но ЭТО ФАКТ.

Comment: FileZilla конечно круто, но FTP коннект рвется периодически, а файлов очень много

Answer (score 1):

1. CPanel делает архивы используя обычный tar (+gzip)
2. Файлы с русскими именами прекрасно туда попадают
3. Для того, чтобы обратно достать их, нужно лишь чтобы локаль была такой же как при сжатии (как правило, это utf-8 т.е. en_US.UTF-8)

Comment: Распаковываю под Виндой 7zip или TC встроенный - один фиг ниче не распаковывает правильно. Там вообще 3 варианта все три пробовал - ничего не выходит

Comment: и не выйдет..  windows что вы от него хотите, вы еще попросите чтобы права из tar сохранялись при распаковке ))

Comment: Да что за глуппости, неужели вариантов не может быть?